# Show Dialog After Thread is Finish

Tags: android, multithreading

I want show dialog after finish Thread.
In thread I am changing TextView's Value like as 0 to 100...
When TextView Value is reach 100 then i want to show dialog..

What i do for it.
Thanks in advance...
Code Snippet:

```
 final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
 {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                synchronized (this) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        for(int i=0 ; i<speed; i++)
                       {
                            final int value=i+1;
                            wait(3000/speed);      
                            Test.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override public void run()
                            {
                                accText.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                            }});

                        }

                    }
                   catch (InterruptedException e)
                   {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }

            }
        });
       thread.start();
```

this is asyntask code snippet...

```
   class setTextBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String , Integer, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    } 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        Thread th = new Thread();
        int value;
        for(int i=0 ; i<speed; i++)
       {
            value=i+1;
            publishProgress(value);
            try {
                th.sleep(3000/speed);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        accText.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
        System.out.println("Value=="+values[0]);

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {

               showShareDialog();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) explains how you can create dialogs.

Please note that you will have to do any dialog creation code on the UI thread.

You already have code that runs something on the UI thread, just do that outside the loop,but with the dialog creation code inside.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html): subclass `AsyncTask`, override `doInBackground()` to execute your time consuming action on another thread, and then override `onPostExecute()` to show your dialog.

Note that you cannot change UI elements from a non-UI (background) thread. `AsyncTask` takes care of that for you: it calls `doInBackground()` on a new thread and then calls `onPostExecute()` on the UI thread as soon as the background task is complete.

Comment: I want change value of TextView.. and if i use it then it not given me value in sync...

Comment: Just to be clear, you have: 1) subclassed AsyncTask, 2) overridden doInBackground to contain the code of your for-loop, 3) overridden onPostExecute to show a dialog and 4) called (new MyTask()).execute() in your activity, and then what exactly happens? The TextEdit updates are done too late?

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is the problem? I could not really understand your comment "and if i use it then it not given me value in sync". Anyway, you shouldn't call sleep on `th` but on the class `Thread` instead. `th` is not running in your case. Also note that you do not need an own `Thread` instance at all, because `AsyncTask` takes care of that for you.

Comment: Yes now i change it "Thread.sleep(...)" but my problem is that i want value from o to 100 in sequence... and it is return me like as 1,2,3,4,5,1,7,8,2,3,5,6, .....etc (it is not in sequence.) So, this is my problem...

Comment: So the values also repeat themselves, like in your above number sequence?

Comment: This seems to me as if the task is running twice at the same time. Are you sure you are only starting it once?

Comment: this seems unlikely. could you please put a log message into onPreExecute and then check logcat to see if it appears twice?